# how to read additional parameters in [...nextauth] signIn() callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jwt, next-auth

According to [Next Auth docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#additional-parameters), I can pass additional parameters to the `/authorize` endpoint through the third argument of `signIn()`.

They show two examples:

```
signIn("identity-server4", null, { prompt: "login" }) // always ask the user to re-authenticate
signIn("auth0", null, { login_hint: "info@example.com" }) // hints the e-mail address to the provider
```

However, there is no full working example and I'm unable to read any additional parameters that I've added in `/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`. Can anyone show me how to read these additional parameters in, for example, the `signIn() callback?`

Here's a simple example to illustrate what I mean:

`/index.jsx`

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react"

export default function EmailLink() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

    const submitUser = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        signIn('email', 
            {email, callbackUrl: '/dashboard', redirect: false}, 
            {addedParam: "My added parameter"}) // <- MY ADDITIONAL PARAMETER!
        }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitUser}>
            Email: <input type='email' placeholder="Enter email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            <button type="submit">Email Link</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

`/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email"

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({
      server: {
        host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        }
      },
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn(user, account, profile, email, credentials) {
      const loginProvider = user.account.provider
      if (loginProvider === "email") { 
        console.log("User:", user)
        console.log("Account:", account)
        console.log("Profile:", profile)
        console.log("Email:", email)
        console.log("Credentials:", credentials)
        return user
      }
    },
})
```

Output results from `signIn()` callback:

```
User: {
  user: { email: 'user@domain.com', id: 'user@domain.com' },
  account: {
    providerAccountId: 'user@domain.com',
    userId: 'user@domain.com',
    type: 'email',
    provider: 'email'
  },
  email: { verificationRequest: true }
}
Account undefined
Profile undefined
Email undefined
Credentials undefined
```

As you can see, my additional parameter `{addedParam: "My added parameter"}` doesn't show up in any of the objects. How do I read this added parameter in `/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`?

Comment: Here's some sample code in case anyone wants to help me with this issue:
https://github.com/benwhut/nextauth-additionalparams

Comment: From what I can tell, the additional params can only be used with the `Credentials` provider or a custom OAuth provider.

Comment: what about padding the additional info through cookie and accessing it in the `signIn` callback?

Answer (score 2):

It's not explained very clearly in the documentation, but to consume the data passed in the third parameter of `signIn()` and `signOut()`, the provider being used needs to have a `authorize()` callback as it's second parameter.

`EmailProvider` doesn't provide this callback, but a provider like `CredentialsProvider` does.

`EmailProvider` example from the docs:

```js
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
...
providers: [
  EmailProvider({
    server: {
      host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
      port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD
      }
    },
    from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM
  }),
],
```

`CredentialsProvider` example from the docs (note the `req` object being passed to `authorize()`):

```js
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
...
providers: [
  CredentialsProvider({
    name: "Credentials",
    credentials: {
      username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
      password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
    },
    async authorize(credentials, req) {
      // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
      const user = { id: "1", name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com" }

      if (user) {
        // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
        return user
      } else {
        // If you return null then an error will be displayed advising the user to check their details.
        return null

        // You can also Reject this callback with an Error thus the user will be sent to the error page with the error message as a query parameter
      }
    }
  })
]
```

The problem is at this point, using extra params is not compatible with `EmailProvider`.

Comment: You could try passing the additional parameters from client to server with a cookie

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure the addedParam must go in the same object as email and callbackUrl:

```
const submitUser = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  signIn('email', { 
    email, 
    callbackUrl: '/dashboard', 
    redirect: false, 
    addedParam: "My added parameter" 
  })
}
```

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried, but the output is exactly the same as my original post, 'addedParam' doesn't show up